# store values to struct array values C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, parameter-passing

I'm trying to read a file and store the values into struct array then pass the values to a function. the first printf shows the right values but the second one gives all 0. when passing the values to the function it passes all 0 too.

```
input data
0   1
0   2 
0   3
0   4
0   5
```

```
typedef struct  
{
  int brust_time[MAX];
  int arrival_time[MAX];
}Time;


int main()
{ 
  Time *foo;
  FILE *fr;
  char str[10];
  int x = 0;
  int m;

  fr = fopen("read.txt", "rt");

  while(fgets(str, 10, fr) != NULL)
  {
    x++;
    foo = (Time *) malloc(sizeof(Time));
    sscanf(str, "%d  %d", foo[x].arrival_time,foo[x].brust_time );
    printf("x: %d B:%d\n", *foo[x].arrival_time, *foo[x].brust_time);
  }

  for( m = 0; m <x; m++)
    printf("*****x: %d ******B:%d\n", *foo[m].arrival_time, *foo[m].brust_time);

  SJF(foo[x].brust_time,foo[x].arrival_time, x);
  fclose(fr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Foo is being set to a new memory range in each iteration.  you don't have an array. you are only getting the last handle to the last run.  You could make this a linked list and assigning the previous foo a property of the next foo called next.  Research Linked Lists.

Comment: I'm sorry there's just too much stuff that's wrong in what you have. Start much smaller (read a single line, don't dynamically allocate anything, and make sure you add code to check the return value of all the functions that can fail - i.e. fopen and scanf at least). Turn on your compiler's warnings to the maximum, and fix all errors and warnings (fix, don't hide). Only once that program works 100% even if you feed it bad output should you proceed. Make sure you understand the difference between arrays and pointers too.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX 10

typedef struct 
   {
   int brust_time;
   int arrival_time;
   }Time;

int main()
   {
   int rCode=0;
   Time *foo = NULL;
   FILE *fr = NULL;
   char str[10];
   int x = 0;
   int m;

   /* Open the data file in read (text) mode) */
   errno=0;
   fr = fopen("read.txt", "rt");
   if(NULL == fr)
      {
      rCode=errno;
      fprintf(stderr, "fopen() failed.  errno[%d]\n", errno);
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Allocate an array of 'Time' structures large enough to hold all the data. */
   foo = malloc(MAX * sizeof(Time));
   if(NULL == foo)
      {
      rCode=ENOMEM;
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed.\n");
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

   /* Read, parse, and store each line's data in the array of structures. */
   while(x<MAX)
      {
      /* Read a line. */
      errno=0;
      if(NULL == fgets(str, 10, fr))
         {
         if(feof(fr))
            break;

         rCode=errno;
         fprintf(stderr, "fgets() failed.  errno[%d]\n", errno);
         goto CLEANUP;
         }

      /* Parse & store */ 
      sscanf(str, "%d  %d", &foo[x].arrival_time, &foo[x].brust_time );
      ++x;
      }

   /* Generate report. */
   for(m = 0; m < x; m++)
       printf("*****x: %d ******B:%d\n", foo[m].arrival_time, foo[m].brust_time);

/* Restore system. */
CLEANUP:

   /* Free Time structure array. */
   if(foo)
      free(foo);

   /* Close the file. */
   if(fr)
      fclose(fr);

   return(rCode);
   }
```